# Horizontal scroll loop in Cargo Collective

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I'm trying to add an horizontal loop to my page but when I try to add the javascript cargo tells me that the script has been disabled. Why does that happen? Is there a way to implement that java without having problems? Is it right to add the javascript in the tag script at the end? This is where I've took the code from: https://codepen.io/lemmin/pen/bqNBpK

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
  <div class="pane"><div>Looping Horizontal Scroll</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>2</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>3</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>4</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>5</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>Last</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>Looping Horizontal Scroll</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-size:200%;
}

#page {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:#CCC;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
}
.pane {
  flex:0 0 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}

.pane:nth-child(4n+2)  {
  background-color: #49E83E;
}
.pane:nth-child(4n+3)  {
  background-color: #EDDE05;
}
.pane:nth-child(4n+4)  {
  background-color: #E84B30;
}
.pane:last-child {
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
var page = document.getElementById('page');
var last_pane = page.getElementsByClassName('pane');
last_pane = last_pane[last_pane.length-1];
var dummy_x = null;

window.onscroll = function () {
  var y = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  page.scrollLeft = -y;
  
  var diff = window.scrollY - dummy_x;
  if (diff > 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, diff);
  }
  else if (window.scrollY == 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, dummy_x);
  }
}
// Adjust the body height if the window resizes.
window.onresize = resize;
// Initial resize.
resize();

// Reset window-based vars
function resize() {
  var w = page.scrollWidth-window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight;
  document.body.style.height = w + 'px';
  
  dummy_x = last_pane.getBoundingClientRect().left+window.scrollY;
}
</script>
```